# RECOVERY FILE DEST - incorrect space used

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

please advice

I created Oracle DB with FRA.
Total Size equals to 50GB.

But report shows that SPACE_USED bigger than SPACE_LIMIT.

```
col space_limit format 999,999,999,999
col space_used  format 999,999,999,999
select space_limit, space_used from v$recovery_file_dest;

     SPACE_LIMIT       SPACE_USED
---------------- ----------------
  53,687,091,200  505,911,314,944

1 row selected.
```

Other SQL Report:

```
set lines 120
col name     format a36
col size_mb  format 999,999,999,999
col used_mb  format 999,999,999,999
col pct_used format 999
TTITLE CENTER "Fast Recovery Area Space Status" SKIP 1 -
CENTER =================================
select
   name,
   ceil( space_limit / 1024 / 1024) size_mb,
   ceil( space_used / 1024 / 1024) used_mb,
   decode( nvl( space_used, 0),0, 0,
   ceil ( ( space_used / space_limit) * 100) ) pct_used
from
    v$recovery_file_dest
order by
   name desc;

                                             Fast Recovery Area Space Status
                                            =================================
NAME                                          SIZE_MB         USED_MB PCT_USED
------------------------------------ ---------------- --------------- --------
/u05/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area             51,200        4,824,75      943

1 row selected.
```

How can I select correct sql report with percentage?

Comment: Maybe you should move the post to - https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From `v$recovery_area_usage`? Have you changed the recovery destination since creating the DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from v$recovery_area_usage;

FILE_TYPE            PERCENT_SPACE_USED PERCENT_SPACE_RECLAIMABLE NUMBER_OF_FILES
-------------------- ------------------ ------------------------- ---------------
CONTROL FILE                          0                         0               0
REDO LOG                              0                         0               0
ARCHIVED LOG                     946.11                         0            2640
BACKUP PIECE                          0                         0               0
IMAGE COPY                            0                         0               0
FLASHBACK LOG                         0                         0               0
FOREIGN ARCHIVED LOG                  0                         0               0

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below and check

```
change archivelog all crosscheck;
report obsolete orphan;
report obsolete;
crosscheck backup;
crosscheck copy;
crosscheck backup of controlfile;
delete noprompt expired backup;
delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
delete noprompt expired backup of controlfile;
delete force noprompt expired copy;
delete force noprompt obsolete orphan;
delete force noprompt obsolete;
```

Comment: Please explain why he should run these commands. He is asking for information on the percentage of "SPACE_USED" not deletes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are answering a 4 yo question wihtout any explaination. Please expand your point and improve your answer